# adding buttons with shortcuts, or shortcuts only for ant tasks in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am working on a project which has an Ant script for all lifecycle phases.
The project, divided in small projects, is meant to be developed with Eclipse. The common version is the Indigo One.

Basically I am interested on putting a series of buttons with a shortcut each, or at least a shortcut only, to execute some of the main tasks.
The relevant tasks are:

- fast build: this involves only the front end classes and jsps, I have solved this easily in the builders panel by adding an Ant build which call the task, for later review with the buttons issue, because there's no shortcut for the "Project->Build Project"
- full build: occasionally I need to launch a task for a complete build, which is taking quite some time in respect to a simple build
- deploy: this task simply packs the war file and deploy to a local jboss location, at the moment I am launching the jboss server manually via shell script, but I was thinking for a convenient way to have it launched by Eclipse if not already started

thanks

Comment: Seems http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/36738/119782/#msg_119782 is the preferred alternative

Comment: That could be the answer, unfortunately I cannot mark a comment as solution. I gave a vote, that's the only thing I can do.

Comment: No problem. I thought one of the answer below was close enough of the thread I referenced, which is why I didn't duplicate said answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a couple of "ant build" launch configurations to run your ant script(s) with specified ant targets and configuration.

Run>External Tool...>External Tools Configurations... and then select "ant build" and press "New launch configuration". On "Main" tab specify buildfile and directory on "Target" select targets you want to run on "Properties" add additional properties or specify property file.

It would be also a good idea to give each of launch configurations a descriptive name.

Later you can add your defined configuration to favorites for convenience and use them from External Tools (down arrow) on the toolbar 
(See: Run>External Tool...>Organize Favorites...)

Comment: this is quite nice, do you know how to add a shortcut to the external tools ?

Comment: I couldn't find specific mappings, but you can use: Alt+R,E,1 - for first launch, Alt+R,E,2 - for second... etc. You can also map in Preferences>Keys the key shortcut to the last launched tool (I quite often use rerun of the last one so I have added shortcut Alt+Shift+E for that.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Ant view, which is integrated into Eclipse. Press Ctrl+3 (cmd+3 on mac I think) and type Ant, and then open the view. Click on "Add buildfile" and add the relevant build file. It'll then have the ant tasks listed in the view which you can just run from there.